# Is the Raspberry Pi polarity protected on the USB?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

I am building a Pi into some equipment just to drive a display. Now this is normally powered by a USB lead with the usual 5VDC. So I will have to cut the USB cable and put ferrules on the leads (omitting the data lines) to connect to the 5VDC supply on the DIN rail.

The question being, if someone gets the polarity wrong in production, will it destroy the Pi, or is there internal protection? Is there typically internal polarity protection on other devices that take power from USB eg phones? Is putting in such protection feasible given (say) the voltage drop produced by a simple diode? What other protection circuits exist that do not drop voltage (if this is even possible)?

Comment: Why don't you check the schematic?

Comment: @LeonHeller Looking for a general answer if there is one. So I just modified the question

Comment: @LeonHeller Looks like a hefty zener across the power-gnd

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer. There is no body that would be able to enforce such a requirement, so you can't assume anything.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the model. Some seem to have a polarity protection MOSFET, newer models only have a diode which would simply blow up.

Comment: @TurboJ The diode may well work to force the USB i/f on the driving side to fold back. But a regular PSU will blow it up

Comment: @DirkBruere If this is likely to be a problem, then it looks like an additional step in production to confirm the polarity is correct is would be a good idea.

Comment: Why not insert a polarity diode yourself when you *"have to cut the USB cable and put ferrules on the leads"*?

Comment: Note that USB connectors have a polarity protection by their dimensions. So, theoretically, there is no need for polarity protection. Unless someone is cutting the cable ;-)

Comment: There could be no "general answer", all depends on particular model and schematics. Simple Google search for {is power on raspberry pi 3 reverse polarity protected} leads to many links, this one in particular. Pleeese... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88854/58665

Comment: I would not expect polarity protection in general. Even less on something that is intended to be used with a polarized connector. You can't protect against someone else's wrong design

Answer (score 2):

The 3B+ is not intentionally reverse polarity protected. However, D7 could clamp it to somewhere around -1.5V, the forward voltage of suppression diodes is quite high.

[image]